How can I jump automatically to the next PDF-page by using corewebview2 in WinForm
I did a WinForm application to view PDF files. I use WebView2 of Microsoft and CoreWebView2.Navigate(pdfFile). The PDF - file ist displayed fine, but I have problems if the PDF file has several pages. It shows me the first page and I get scrollbars to go manually to the next pages which works fine too. But I need to diplay one page after the other automatically. Let's say always after 30 seconds I must display the next page. Until now I didn't find a way to do it. I hope that here is someone who knows how to do it!
What is also disturbing me that I see scrollbars, if it's a multipage PDF-file.
If I enter manually the sequence Ctrl Alt G followed by 2 + Enter page no 2 is displayed
What I have tried:
private Microsoft.Web.WebView2.WinForms.WebView2 webView1;
...
....
webView1.Focus();
SendKeys.SendWait("^(%(g))"); // Ctrl Alt G
SendKeys.SendWait("2~"); // 2 + Enter

My app is running in Full screen, but I use up to 6 webView2 controls and each shows another PDF file. The parameter "#page=3" was helpful and now I use webView1.CoreWebView2.Navigate(pdfFile + "#page=3"). Scrollbars are still visible. Vut a second call webView1.CoreWebView2.Navigate(pdfFile + "#page=4"). doesn't change the page. First I must unload the content and then I can show another page. But by the way your answer help already a lot and now I must find a way that the scrollbar aren't visible.
